# How to copy values from HashMap into an ArrayList using a Pair object class

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

So I am trying to figure out how to move my Pair<Key, Value> from the HashMap that they are originally in, into an ArrayList. Nothing I am doing seems to be working and I am at a loss for how to copy the Keys & Values over.

The Pair class:

```
public class Pair<K,V> {
    private K key;
    private V value;
    public Pair(K key, V value)
    { this.key = key; this.value = value; }
    public K getKey() { return key; }
    public V getValue() { return value; }
}
```

And here is the ArrayList that I am attempting to put them into: `ArrayList<Pair<String,Integer>> wcList = new ArrayList<>();`

For the above ArrayList I am given a HashMap<String, Integer> as a parameter. The return must be an ArrayList<Pair<String, Integer>>

** Using an entrySet does not work for my test cases **

Comment: What is the specific issue you're having?

Comment: @DaveNewton I need to move the pairs from the parameter HashMap into an ArrayList

Comment: Right. What is preventing you from doing so?

Comment: @DaveNewton I understand how to copy the values to individual ArrayLists, such as one for the Keys and one for the Values, but I do not understand how to move both the <Key, Value> into an ArrayList.

Comment: There are multiple ways it can be done. I don't understand what you mean by "using an `entrySet` does not work for my test cases"--*how* the `List` is created is irrelevant; the *content* of the list is the goal. If you can get the map's keys, you can get the map's values. If you have the map's keys and values, you can create the `Pair`. If you can create the `Pair` you can put it into a list. What's the *specific* issue?

Comment: @DaveNewton So I have altered the wcList to be an `ArrayList<Pair<String, Integer>>(listofKeys, listofValues)` with the listofKeys being an ArrayList of the keys, and the listofValues being an ArrayList of the values. This gives me the error "no suitable constructor found for ArrayList however. 

I guess my main question is, how do I get those values into a Pair. Then from their, how would I be able to put those Pairs into an ArrayList.

Comment: If you're given a `HashMap<String, Integer>` what do you need the lists for? Why would you need a list of values if you have a list of keys? You can get the value from the map with the keys. Why can't you use `entrySet`?

Comment: @DaveNewton How would I implement entrySet? I understand how to use it to print a HashMap but don't quite understand how I would use it to copy the values into an ArrayList. I tried casting the values using the entrySet and I cannot cast entrySet to Pair.

Comment: "One by one" seems to be the answer to a lot of the questions you're asking.

Comment: @unstableindividual You do not need to cast or convert to your `Pair` class, you don't need your `Pair` class at all! The `Map.Entry` interface does exactly what you want your `Pair` class to do. See my Answer for more explanation and code.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

The existing [`Map.Entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.Entry.html) interface does the job of your `Pair` class, including `getKey` & `getValue` methods. In your case, use `Map.Entry < String, Integer >`.

**Example:** From a `Map` of student name (key) to their grade (value), produce a `List` of the key-value pairings, sorted first by their grade (highest first), then by their name alphabetically.

```java
var entriesSorted =
        new TreeSet <>(
                Comparator
                        .comparing( Map.Entry < String, Integer > :: getValue ).reversed()  // Reversed for highest grades first.
                        .thenComparing( Map.Entry < String, Integer > :: getKey )  // Names sort alphabetically.
        );
entriesSorted.addAll(
        Map
                .of(
                        "Alice" , 4 ,  // Student, Grade
                        "Bobby" , 2 ,
                        "Carol" , 3 ,
                        "Davis" , 4 ,
                        "Edith" , 1 ,
                        "Frank" , 3
                )
                .entrySet()
);
var list = List.copyOf( entriesSorted );
```

> list.toString() = [Alice=4, Davis=4, Carol=3, Frank=3, Bobby=2, Edith=1]

Or, if you insist upon your `Pair` class, use `Stream#map` to transfer the key & value from each `Map.Entry` to a new `Pair` object.

```java
List < Pair > list =
        Map
                .of(
                        "Alice" , 4 ,  // Student, Grade
                        "Bobby" , 2 ,
                        "Carol" , 3 ,
                        "Davis" , 4 ,
                        "Edith" , 1 ,
                        "Frank" , 3
                )
                .entrySet()  // Returns a `Set` of `Map.Entry` objects.
                .stream()
                .map( entry -> new Pair( entry.getKey() , entry.getValue() ) )
                .toList();
```

> list = [Pair{key=Edith, value=1}, Pair{key=Alice, value=4}, Pair{key=Carol, value=3}, Pair{key=Frank, value=3}, Pair{key=Bobby, value=2}, Pair{key=Davis, value=4}]

## `Map.Entry` instead of your `Pair`

A [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) already provides what you want.

You imply that you already have a `Map < String , Integer >`, using `HashMap` as your implementation.

You want a `List` of the key-value pairs contained in that Map. To represent those key-value pairs, you created a `Pair` class. But there is **no need for your `Pair` class**. The [`Map.Entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.Entry.html) interface already provides the key-value pairing object you desire. To quote the Javadoc:

> `Map.Entry<K,V>` … A map entry (key-value pair).

A `Map.Entry` object offers `getKey` and `getValue` methods, to access their contents.

You can easily produce a `Set` of those `Entry` objects, with a built-in method on every `Map`.

```
Map< String , Integer > myMap = new HashMap<>() ;
…
Set< String , Integer > pairs = myMap.entrySet() ;
```

A `Set` is appropriate here, because your `HashMap` by definition has no promised order. So a `List`, which keeps elements in a sequence, makes no sense.

### Example code

Here is some example code, using student name mapped to their class grade.

Instead of a `HashMap`, I use an unspecified `Map` implementation produced by the convenient [`Map.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#of(K,V,K,V,K,V,K,V,K,V,K,V)) method.

```java
Map < String, Integer > studentGrades =
        Map.of(
                "Alice" , 4 ,
                "Bob" , 2 ,
                "Carol" , 3 ,
                "Davis" , 4 ,
                "Edith" , 1 ,
                "Frank" , 3
        );
Set < Map.Entry < String, Integer > > entries = studentGrades.entrySet();
entries.forEach( System.out :: println );  // Call `toString` on each `Entry` object.
```

When run:

```
Davis=4
Edith=1
Alice=4
Bob=2
Carol=3
Frank=3
```

You needn't work out that exact type of `Set < Map.Entry < String, Integer > > entries`; just use `var` to let the compiler figure it out.

```
var entries = studentGrades.entrySet();
```

### Ordered set

```
var entries = studentGrades.entrySet();
```

If you want to keep those entries in a specific order, use a [`NavigableSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableSet.html) (or `SortedSet`) such as [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html). You will need to provide the rule by which to order them.

Let’s say we want them sorted by the student’s grades, highest grades first.

```java
NavigableSet < Map.Entry < String, Integer > > entriesByGrade =
        new TreeSet <>(
                Comparator
                        .comparing( Map.Entry < String, Integer > :: getValue ).reversed()
                        .thenComparing( Map.Entry < String, Integer > :: getKey )
        );
entriesByGrade.addAll( entries );
```

> entriesByGrade.toString() = [Alice=4, Davis=4, Carol=3, Frank=3, Bob=2, Edith=1]

If you really need a `List`, you can make one from the `NavigableSet`.

```
List < Map.Entry < String, Integer > > listOfStudentsByGrade = List.copyOf( entriesByGrade );
```

Or more simply, use `var`.

```
var listOfStudentsByGrade = List.copyOf( entriesByGrade );
```

Either way, when run:

> listOfStudentsByGrade.toString() = [Alice=4, Davis=4, Carol=3, Frank=3, Bob=2, Edith=1]

## Using your `Pair` class

As discussed in this Answer, and in the Comments, your `Pair` class is utterly superfluous, with `Map.Entry` already doing its job.

But if you insist, you could easily pull the key & value out of each entry, then put that same key and value into an object of your `Pair` class. Silly, but easy.

```java
List < Pair > list =
        Map
                .of(
                        "Alice" , 4 ,  // Student, Grade
                        "Bobby" , 2 ,
                        "Carol" , 3 ,
                        "Davis" , 4 ,
                        "Edith" , 1 ,
                        "Frank" , 3
                )
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map( entry -> new Pair( entry.getKey() , entry.getValue() ) )
                .toList();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a one-liner.  Stream out the map's entry set, and convert each entry to a `Pair`.  Then collect them into a list.

```
yourMap.entrySet().stream().map(e->new Pair(e.getKey(), e.getValue())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit of code that populates a Map, and then prints out the map contents:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("aardvark", 1);
map.put("bear", 2);
map.put("cat", 3);
System.out.println("map: " + map);

map: {cat=3, aardvark=1, bear=2}
```

Using that map, here's a bit of code that:

- gets each key from the map
- for each key, gets the associated value
- for each key-value pair, it creates a new Pair object (using the Pair code you posted)
- each Pair is then added to a List
- at the end, it prints out the contents of the list
- also, I added a `toString()` method to the Pair class (posted below) so that the list printing is more informative

```
List<Pair<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (String key : map.keySet()) {
    Integer value = map.get(key);
    Pair<String, Integer> pair = new Pair<>(key, value);
    list.add(pair);
}
System.out.println("list: " + list);

list: [Pair{key=cat, value=3}, Pair{key=aardvark, value=1}, Pair{key=bear, value=2}]
```

Here's the addition to Pair so that the list contents can be printed nicely:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Pair{" +
            "key=" + key +
            ", value=" + value +
            '}';
}
```

You could also solve it with streams:

```
List<Pair<String, Integer>> list = map
        .keySet()
        .stream()
        .map(key -> new Pair<>(key, map.get(key)))
        .toList();
```

Answer (score -2):

The below code seperates the keys and values from HashMap and creates 2 ArrayLists to hold them.

Please refer the extract method.

> For the above ArrayList I am given a HashMap<String, Integer> as a parameter. The return must be an ArrayList<Pair<String, Integer>>

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    map.put("one", 1);
    map.put("two", 2);
    map.put("three", 3);
    extract(map);
}

public static ArrayList<Pair<String, Integer>> extract(HashMap map)
{
    ArrayList<Pair<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<Pair<String,Integer>>();
    ArrayList<String> mapKeys = new ArrayList<String>(map.keySet());
    ArrayList<Integer> mapValues = new ArrayList<Integer>(map.values());
    Pair p;
    for(int i=0; i<map.size(); i++) {
        p = new Pair(mapKeys.get(i), mapValues.get(i));
        list.add(p);
    }
    
    list.stream().forEach(e ->System.out.println(e.toString()));
    return list;
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's any guarantee that `map.values()` will be iterated in the order corresponding to the iteration order of `map.keySet()`.  This will probably work sometimes.

Comment: Why won't they iterate in the same order? They are fetched from the same HashMap.

Comment: Oh, they might well come back in the same order.  What I'm saying is that I don't think the specification guarantees that they will.

Comment: The keys are returned as a [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet--), and the values are returned as a [Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--). There are no guarantees about the ordering of either.

Comment: @SmitChawda Read the Javadoc of `Map`. To quote (emphasis mine): The order of a map is defined as the order in which the iterators on the map's collection views return their elements. Some map implementations, like the `TreeMap` class, make specific guarantees as to their order; **others, like the `HashMap` class, do not.**

Comment: The `SortedMap` specification guarantees that the entry set and the values collection will be iterated in the same order.  But if your `Map` is not a `SortedMap`, there's no such guarantee.

Comment: @SmitChawda FYI: Study up on `NavigableMap` & `NavigableSet` (and `SortedMap` & `SortedSet`) as shown in [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73131910/642706).